# How to make the slim scroll is visible in all time?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slimscroll

I used the slim scroll plugin in the qtip plugin. The slim scroll is visible when the mouse is enter into the qtip.

My code is:

```
$(api.elements.content).find('.tabContent').slimScroll({
   height: "auto", 
   color: "#FFF", 
   width: "auto", 
   size: "10px", 
   alwaysVisible: true
});
```

But i want to make the slim scroll is visible in all time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using mac with OS X they by default hiding a scroll-bar and show each time when you move a mouse over the element which has this bar. Also i'm going to mention that this plugin by default has a scroll-bar always visible so this is your potential issue

Here is some sort of tutorial how to force OS X to always show the scroll-bars. http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/03/show-scroll-bars-mac-os-x-lion/